# Running jQuery if on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile

I have a slidebox per sae on my site, and we use media queries to include a mobile stylesheet which does a lot of `display: none`, unfortunately. The slidebox was one of these `display:none` until we decided it was quite an important part of the site (displaying latest top content etc) so I've decided to add it back in.

Anyway, to cut a long story short, it uses tabs to jump between each slide, and within the tab is the title of the content ie. 'Big Event' or 'Sign Up Here' etc. On a mobile device, these are too long, so I've used to some jQuery to change the text to 1, 2, 3, 4... etc. based on screen width, which saves up a lot of room.

```
<!-- This is only for the mobile site -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($(window).width() < 500) {
    $('#newsTabsControl li:nth-child(1) a').text('1');
    $('#newsTabsControl li:nth-child(2) a').text('2');
    $('#newsTabsControl li:nth-child(3) a').text('3');
    $('#newsTabsControl li:nth-child(4) a').text('4');
    $('#newsTabsControl li:nth-child(5) a').text('5');
}
});
</script>
```

This is the only way I thought of doing it. When I look at it on my mobile device (iPhone) it works most times, but sometimes doesn't do it at all - a bit inconsistent.

Any ideas on how to make this easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS Media Queries for this.

More information can be seen here: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries

I had in mind something like this:

> HTML

```
<div class="desktop-menu"><!-- HTML FOR DESKTOP --></div>

<div class="mobile-menu"><!-- HTML FOR MOBILE --></div>
```

> CSS

```
.mobile-menu  {display:none}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

.desktop-menu {display:none}
.mobile-menu  {display:inline}

}
```

Comment: I have updated your answer to actually provide resources. Please try to do this whenever possible. The OP may search for Media Queries and get a completely incorrect idea about what they are and how to use them.

Comment: @Richard The question was: "Any ideas on how to make this easier?" You can accomplish your goal without JS...

Comment: @madflow I think you've misinterpreted what I'm after here. I need to wrap the JS in a conditional statement so it only loads if the site is on mobile. I'm well aware of media queries, but this only works for CSS and HTML, whereas I need the JS to load only if mobile. Apologies if I wasn't clear. I need the JS to change the text of list items - you cannot do this with CSS.

Comment: @Richard I wanted to provide an alternative, which I consider easier. I am aware what you wanted in the first place - but since you said it does not work with JS properly - I mentioned the technology which was invented for cases like these. In my approach you would have to write two menus/tabs:  One for the desktop and one for mobile.